# Android List and Array set

Tags: android, arrays, list, set

I'm trying to save this info on a Service that is triggered by receiving a call but it's crashing after I use the .set

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDateTimeString = df.format(calendar.getTime());

List<String> lastCall = new ArrayList<String>();

lastCall.set(0, currentDateTimeString);
lastCall.add("12:22:12 12-03-2014");
lastCall.add("22:06:34 14-07-2013");
lastCall.add("12:22:12 12-03-2012");
lastCall.add("22:06:34 14-07-2011");
lastCall.add("12:22:12 12-03-2010");

if (lastCall.size() > 5){
    lastCall.remove(6);
}

editor.putString("lastCall", new Gson().toJson(lastCall));
editor.commit();
```

I'm trying to save only the 5 last calls, since the .set should add in the 1st position until gets 6 strings and the 6th is removed.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to change to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: read the doc. `set`  throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException  if location < 0 || location >= size()`. In your case, `size()` at this point is 0, since there is no item yet.

Comment: Hi @njzk2 can you make an answer with an example?

Comment: i don't really understand what you are trying to do. Why are you adding 6 elements to the list, only to remove the 6th immediately after?

Comment: @njzk2 I want to save the last 5 calls and the 1st item of the array should be the last call. I know that I might be doing this wrong but I'm trying to do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figure it out, I was adding the strings to array, saving and reading on the other activity but I was not reading before saving in the array... So that way I was always rewriting the entire array without getting the last strings..

And in this case the .add is the best.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDateTimeString = df.format(calendar.getTime());    

List<String> lastCall;
lastCall = new Gson().fromJson(blockerPreferences.getString("lastCall", null), new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());

lastCall.add(currentDateTimeString);

if (lastCall.size() == 6){
    lastCall.remove(0);
}

editor.putString("lastCall", new Gson().toJson(lastCall));
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use set? 
As far as I can understand you want to put the **currentDateTimeString** at the 0 position? 
If so - use:

```
lastCall.add(0, currentDateTimeString);
```

**set** is used to **replace** an existing record at the specific index. If you don't have a record at that position - it will crash.

Comment: Hi there, I want to place that string on the 1st record but never replace the remaining records. After that delete the 6th string if exist. If I use .add it will replace.

Comment: @FilipeOS, add(index, object) will **insert** an object at that position and not replace the currently occupying it object. Using **set** will result in replacing the object at that position. Maybe ArrayList is not your best choice of a collection. Use Dequeue for example.